# Django Integrity error from Abstractbaseuser

Tags: django

```
IntegrityError at /
UNIQUE constraint failed: pages_profile.username
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.9
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: pages_profile.username
```

How would you update an Abstractuser's custom avatar field?
Specifically **obj = Profile.objects.create(avatar = img)**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .forms import UserProfileForm
from .models import Profile

def index(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            img = form.cleaned_data.get("avatar")
            obj = Profile.objects.create(
                                 avatar = img
                                 )
            obj.save()
            print(obj)
            return redirect(request, "home.html", obj)

    else:
        form = UserProfileForm()
    context['form']= form
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Profile(AbstractUser):
    
    """ bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) """
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='', null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions

from pages.models import Profile

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('avatar',)

    def clean_avatar(self):
        avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']

        try:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)

            #validate dimensions
            max_width = max_height = 1000
            if w > max_width or h > max_height:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Please use an image that is '
                     '%s x %s pixels or smaller.' % (max_width, max_height))

            #validate content type
            main, sub = avatar.content_type.split('/')
            if not (main == 'image' and sub in ['jpeg', 'pjpeg', 'gif', 'png']):
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please use a JPEG, '
                    'GIF or PNG image.')

            #validate file size
            if len(avatar) > (20 * 1024):
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Avatar file size may not exceed 20k.')

        except AttributeError:
            """
            Handles case when we are updating the user profile
            and do not supply a new avatar
            """
            pass

        return avatar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

```
IntegrityError at /
UNIQUE constraint failed: pages_profile.username
```

is implying that there is already another profile object with the same username that you are trying to create.

To fix this you need to update the existing profile if it already exists.

You can use django's `create_or_update` like so

```py
obj, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
    username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
    defaults={'avatar': img},
)
```

this will make django update any existing Profile object with `username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')`

if such a profile object does not exist, then it will be created.

Comment: Now it gives Exception Value: 
NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_profile.username.

Comment: that means that your username is NULL. you will have to check what key the username is being sent in the form. `form.cleaned_data.get('username')` would need to change to something else